# Could not build Objective-C module, when using swift in objective-c module

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

In an iOS application I have a subproject (not cocoapods) in which I have included a swift file and ObjC file (that is used by the swift file). XCode automatically created a bridging file but could not build it because apparantly bridging is not allowed in a framework. The workaround that I used was to add the objective-c header to the umbrella file and it worked. Now I need to use a swift class from ObjC. I have `define module` to set to YES, the generated file Framework-Swift.h . But when I try to import it in objective-c i get

> Could not build Objective-C module

The closest I got after some googleing was this answer:

> Ah gotcha. It looks like you're building a mixed Swift & Objective-C
>   pod - if that's the case, Xcode will try to import
>    within the generated -Swift.h header.
>   You'll need to create the header manually and add imports for the
>   Objective-C classes that you want to expose to Swift.
>
> CocoaPods generates an umbrella header automatically and imports it
>   within the .modulemap, but Xcode doesn't use that when generating the
>   -Swift.h header

But I am unsure what header needs to be created manually. 
Any ideeas or pointer about using swift in an objective-c framework ? In both ways ?

Answer (score 15):

I also had similar issue when using Swift pods in my Swift project containing several targets. No Objective-C code at all. I tried to clear build folder, pods cache, derived data - nothing worked.

Solution:

Open the Build Settings for a target that contains your module code. Set the "Install Objective-C Compatibility Header" to "No"

[image]

Comment: For me the answer was to set it to NO then set it back to YES.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a great and simple article](https://jsorge.net/2019/01/23/mixed-language-framework) that wraps up this case:

1. DEFINES_MODULE=YES
2. To use ObjC classes in Swift, create a bridging header and specify path to it in the build settings
3. To use Swift classes in ObjC, `#import <ModuleName/ModuleName-Swift.h>` in your `*.m` file (use `@class SwiftClass;` forward declaration in `*.h` file, if needed)
4. For swift classes and their members to be visible to objc

   1. inherit your class from `NSObject`
   2. prepend it with `@objcMembers`
   3. make both the class and its members `public`